# Conflict ListField click & menu click

Tags: java, blackberry

In my application i have put listfield on the screen. Now my problem is that when i am clicking the list item (while list item has the focus on it) it does activities asopen the menu.

I want to disable the menu while clicking list. I want that if i click the list item it should perform only the necessary task defined in the item click event, Not shown the menu with it.

Any body has some idea about about that?

Answer (score 7):

Override the `navigationClick()` for your `ListField` to consume the click event (should return true) without calling `super.navigationClick()`:

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    Status.show("Clicked on item: " + myList.getSelectedIndex());
    return true;
}
```